# aws cli error - assembly containing this type

Tags: amazon-web-services

Am trying to call an aws cli command from a windows powershell script file - ps1 file. Am getting assembly not loaded error - "verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded".
The error is thrown by the below line

New-Object -Type Amazon.CloudFormation.Model.Parameter

I realize that I need to load some assembly but not sure which dll I need to load.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to have .NET 4.5 installed to install WMF/PS 4.0 (otherwise it silently fails), but you have to have SP3 Update 5 or later for Exchange 2010 installed (not sure if you can update Exchange afterward and have it work).

Also You need to load the assembly. In PSH V2 this is very easy for a framework assembly:

```
add-type -assemblyName "System.ServiceProcess"
```